# Meaning of dask delayed

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I want to split my df to two dfs.

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv(r'D:\Amr\Amr.csv',error_bad_lines=False, engine="python")
import numpy as np
dfs = dask.delayed(np.split)(df,2)
df0=dfs[0]
dask.delayed(df0.to_csv)('file1.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

The result showing, Delayed('to_csv-386b2047-2ed0-4317-bdf7-65e3aa2695af').
What is its meaning.

Comment: Did you seek out the dask documentation page about Delayed? https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dask delayed function decorates your functions so that they operate lazily. Rather than executing your function immediately, it will defer execution, placing the function and its arguments into a task graph.

In other words, this means that the code will only be executed when the results are needed (so when you perform an action using the results). This is also referred to as call-by-need.

Comment: Then how can I save df0 in above example? Where can I get more information about this?

Comment: I'm guessing you've still got to call .compute(). I'm not an expert in dask, haven't use it that much (I use spark instead). But more information could be found in their extensive and clear [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) :)